# Compiling with operator() under GCC 3.3 Problem in Boost

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, random

I have the following snippet:

```
#include <boost/random/lognormal_distribution.hpp>
#include <boost/random/lagged_fibonacci.hpp> 

int main() {

  const double mean  = 0.0;
  const double sigma = 1.0;

  boost::lognormal_distribution<double> lognorm_dist(mean, sigma);
  boost::lagged_fibonacci44497 engine;

  // the following line give error in GCC 3.3
  const double value = lognorm_dist.operator() <boost::lagged_fibonacci44497>((engine)); 

}
```

It compile fine under

```
i686-apple-darwin9-g++-4.0.1 (GCC) 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5465)
```

But under:

```
g++ (GCC) 3.3.3 (SuSE Linux)
```

It gave the following error:

```
Mycode.cc:10:error: `operator()' not defined
```

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: struct f { template<typename> void operator()(int) { } }; int main() { f f_; f_.operator()<int>(0); }  does that compile?

Comment: no it doesn't. I've tested your snippet.

Comment: why do you provide explicit brackets at all? just call it like lognorm_dist(engine);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just `lognorm_dist( engine );`? Providing "function-like" syntax is the whole point of operator(). That said, `lognorm_dist.template operator() <boost::lagged_fibonacci44497>((engine))` should solve your compilation issues if I am not mistaken.

Comment: just for the record :) should be noted that it is a bug in the gcc3.3 compiler: lognorm_dist in here is not dependent on template parameters. with a conforming compiler the template disambiguation is not needed. (see the sample code i put in the comments to the question)